# neo4j REST API Authentication and Authorization

Tags: neo4j

I input

```
http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j
```

on the web browser and I receive the message:

```
{
"errors" : [ {
"message" : "No authorization header supplied.",
"code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed"
} ]
}
```

I search the document on [neo4j](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html) and it says that:

```
Authenticate by sending a username and a password to Neo4j using HTTP Basic Auth. Requests should include an Authorization header, with a value of Basic <payload>, where "payload" is a base64 encoded string of "username:password".

Example request

GET http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6c2VjcmV0 

Example response

200: OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

I'm using web browser to view information, how can I "include an Authorization header" in web browser(Firefox)? I don't understand what it says. How to input these example request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to pass the authentication header with just your browser is to use in-URL authentication:

`http://username:password@localhost:7474/user/neo4j`

---

More generally, when testing REST APIs, it's best to use a command-line tool such as curl rather than a browser.  If you're on Linux/Mac then you're likely to have curl already installed.  If you're on Windows there are downloads of curl available.

Curl allows you to fine-tune the headers you send as follows:

```
curl --header 'Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0' 'http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j'
```

Or more simply you can use the `--user` option:

```
curl --user 'myusername:mypassword' 'http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j'
```

---

Purely as an aside, the WWW-Authenticate header in the response from Neo4J is as follows:

```
WWW-Authenticate: None
```

If instead it contained a value for the scheme and realm, then Firefox would have popped up a dialogue prompting you for a username and password:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="WallyWorld"
```

Upon entering the username/password, FF would send a subsequent request with the appropriate Authorization header containing the base64-encoded value of the provided username:password.

More detailed info on HTTP Basic Authentication is given here: [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#page-5)

Comment: Good answer. I also find clients such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) useful. I have no affiliation to either I should point out!

Comment: that means I have to use a tool to send the request to api?

Comment: In the case of curl, curl is a simple command utility which you use in place of your browser.  Postman is a utility which sits inside the Chrome browser, and Fiddler is a proxy which sits between your browser and the outside world.  A simple way you can proceed is to use in-URL authentication as follows:  `http://username:password@localhost:7474/user/neo4j`

Comment: @ANguyen to be clear, you can just input `http://username:password@localhost:7474/user/neo4j` (obviously with the correct username/password) into your browser and you should be able to proceed.  More generally, it's better to use one of the suggested tools as they give you more control over what is being sent, as well as better visibility of responses.

Comment: @Ben Rowland I input http://neo4j:123456@localhost:7474/user/neo4j which neo4j and 123456 are username and password respectively. Firefix shows a dialog something like you are going to login but this site doesn't require authentication, it can be a trick... When I click Yes to the dialog, it still shows the message No authorization header supplied.